# Will I have any problems with this combination of fish?

Tags: fish, multi-pet-families, compatibility

I've got a 6gallon tank housing a total of 9 fishes,

1 Betta
4 Neon Tetras
2 Golden Mbuna
2 Orange Zebras

So far all fishes are doing fine, my betta is silent and doesnt harm other fishes also the same for the tetras and mbunas. The zebras are very much playful chasing each other and rest of the other fishes except for the betta. I got a few live plants in my tank and a lot of hiding places also.

I would like to know if this combination is good to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orange Zebras is a fairly ambiguous title. Are these cichlids or zebra danios or something else?

The Golden Mbuna and possibly Orange Zebras if they're the cichlids that go by this name, are too large and aggressive for this size of tank. Those fish need something closer to the 50 - 75 gallon minimum range, ideally over 100 gallons due to aggression.

It's typically not a good idea to keep neons with any cichlid other than a few South and Central American ones like angelfish, discus, apistogramma, and rams (mikrogeophagus ramirezi) as they'll eventually become dinner. It's also possible they will pester or kill the beta as well.

So basically, definitely no on the cichlids for both tank size and keeping them with these other fish. Otherwise if the orange zebras are zebra danios they should be fine. The tank size is still on the small end, I definitely wouldn't put any more fish in there, and make sure to keep up on water changes, but it should work with proper maintinence.

Comment: Thank you Jestep for your reply. Both my Zebras are Zebra Danios.

Comment: My mbunas are so far keeping away from other fishes they are already an inch or two. Will they grow in size.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the social aspect and fish getting attacked/eaten by other fish, you should also consider what a healty habitat is for the different types of fish you have or want.  
For the Betta the water should be idealy at least 25°C, for the Danios that is actually already a bit too much. So that's not really a good match.  
 And Neon Tetra's are very active fish and like to hang out in groups. So for a tank of this size I would not recommend them.  They need more space to swim, and their behaviour will look nicer if you have a larger group (at least 6-8, preferably more).
  Basically, I would only suggest a Betta for such small tanks.